# Title regular expression

Tags: python, regex

source code

```
HTML = "<title>RUU</title>"
reExtraTitle = re.compile("<title[^>]*>([^<]*)</title>", re.IGNORECASE)
mcTitle = reExtraTitle.match(HTML)
if mcTitle:
    print mcTitle.group()
else:
    print "no Title"
```

Regular expressions help me

Comment: What is the problem? (apart from using regular expressions to parse HTML)

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to StackOverflow. People are hard-handed with the downvotes today, I'm sorry about that. I'm guessing you're not a native english speaker, correct?

Your question fulfills the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) principle, though it shows you're a bit light on the research, and you didn't actually ask a proper question, though it's evident what you're after. Your answer lies in the [re module doc](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group), which you should have read.

You need to `import re` first, and then change

```
print mcTitle.group()
```

to

```
print mcTitle.group(1)
```

As others have hinted, you should perhaps consider using a [dedicated html parser](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) instead of [using regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/566644).